# Can Parallel.ForEach() be used on an Xml document?

Tags: vb.net, parallel.foreach

Having read the [MSDN How To: document on using parallel.foreach()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) I thought I might be able to parallelise some long-running parts of my code - however Visual Studio is producing an error message that I'm struggling to understand, and I'm no longer sure that an `XmlNodeList` is an `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or not!

My code is:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Doc.GetElementsByTagName("Details2"), Sub(Node As XmlNode)
      'do something, for instance
      For Each tAttribute As XmlAttribute In Nodede.Attributes
          debug.writeline(tAttribute.value)
      next
   End Sub)
```

I then get the error message:

> Error BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible
>   'ForEach' can be called with these arguments:
>       'Public Shared Overloads Function ForEach(Of TSource)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), body As Action(Of TSource)) As
>   ParallelLoopResult': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be
>   inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly
>   might correct this error.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why do I need a function? the example uses a sub, and my code doesn't return anything

Comment: my bad, it doesn't matter, the real issue I found was telling it the type of object from the `GetElementsByTagName`. I failed to remove my comment, just posted an answer and failed to remove that comment; sometimes my fingers get ahead of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`XmlNodeList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist) class does implement the `IEnumerable` interface. However, `Parallel.ForEach` expects an `IEnumerable(Of T)` parameter (or, in this case, `IEnumerable(Of XmlNode)`). Therefore, the overload resolution fails. You need to cast the `XmlNodeList` object to `IEnumerable(Of XmlNode)`.

Try something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(doc.GetElementsByTagName("Details2").OfType(Of XmlNode),
                 Sub(node As XmlNode)
                     'do something, for instance
                     For Each tAttribute As XmlAttribute In node.Attributes
                         Debug.WriteLine(tAttribute.Value)
                     Next
                 End Sub)
```

Comment: @MartinKS That is correct. Both `Cast(Of T)` and `OfType(Of T)` would produce the same result in this particular case. However, in other cases where the collection might contain objects of other types, `OfType(Of T)` will only select the `T` objects, whereas `Cast(Of T)` will attempt to cast the other objects to `T` and will throw an exception if the cast fails.